# Reading image from socket with javacv

Tags: android, sockets, javacv

I want to send an image from a desktop pc server (code written in c++) to an android phone (java obviously). I am using OpenCV to load and send the image. On the c++ client I am able to receive and display the image, however I cannot do it in Android program.

How can I read an image from the socket in android app using javacv?

Here is part of the working server code (cv namespace):

```
newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
 if (newsockfd < 0)
      error("ERROR on accept");

 Mat image;
 image = imread(FILE_PATH, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
 if(! image.data ) {
     return -1;
 }
 image = (image.reshape(0,1));
 int  imgSize = image.total()*image.elemSize();
 // Sending data
 n = send(newsockfd, image.data, imgSize, 0);
 if (n < 0)
      error("ERROR writing to socket");
```

Part of the working c++ client code (cv namespace):

```
if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    error("ERROR connecting");

Mat  image = Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC3);
int  imgSize = image.total()*image.elemSize();
uchar sockData[imgSize];

for (int i = 0; i < imgSize; i += n) {
if ((n = recv(sockfd, sockData +i, imgSize  - i, 0)) == -1) {
     exit(1);
    }
}
int ptr=0;
for (int i = 0;  i < image.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++) {
        image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j) = cv::Vec3b(sockData[ptr+ 0],sockData[ptr+1],sockData[ptr+2]);
        ptr=ptr+3;
    }
}
```

In android app I have tried to read the image with DataInputStream but I was unable to convert it to bitmap and display on the screen. LogCat showed `--- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null`, even though connection was successful and `bytesRead` value was bigger than zero and different for each test image. Here is my implementation:

```
private class MyClientThread implements Runnable {

String dstAddress;
int dstPort;
private Socket socket;

MyClientThread() {
    dstAddress = "192.168.1.105";
    dstPort = 8072;         
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        int bytesRead = 0;
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(dstAddress);
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, dstPort);
        try {
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());             
            byte []imgData = new byte [1280*800];
            do{
                bytesRead = din.read(imgData, 0, imgData.length);
                if (bytesRead > -1) //this causes to send and receive the same amount of bytes
                    totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead + bytesRead;
            } while (bytesRead > -1);

            bitmapimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgData, 0, totalBytesRead);                
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
        }
        finally {}
        Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(totalBytesRead));
        socket.close();
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmapimage);
        imgView.invalidate();           
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Logcat error:

```
12-05 11:41:32.720: E/TCP(2496): S: Error
12-05 11:41:32.720: E/TCP(2496): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
12-05 11:41:32.720: E/TCP(2496):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:515)
12-05 11:41:32.720: E/TCP(2496):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:545)
12-05 11:41:32.720: E/TCP(2496):    at com.example.javacvimagereceiver.MainActivity$MyClientThread.run(MainActivity.java:139)
12-05 11:41:32.720: E/TCP(2496):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

where line 139 is: `bitmapimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgData, 0, totalBytesRead);`

Comment: What kind of image or image file is sent by the server?

Comment: Was bytesRead always equal to bytes sent?

Comment: it's a .png file. Actually it's not. It receives less bytes that it sends.

Comment: You only do one read. Make a loop and add the bytes until read returns -1. Make a totalBytesRead variable and compare with bytes sent.

Comment: Now there is always one byte less on the client side, i.e for 1280x800 file `bytesSent = 3072000`, `totalBytesReceived = 3071999`. It's worth mentioning that the image file has only 831 352 bytes. Now LogCat prints `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` invoked by BitmapFactory

Comment: You forgot to adapt the code here.

Comment: `It's worth mentioning that the image file has only 831 352 bytes.`. What do you consider to be the image file. The file before sending? If so. Then what happens before sending? And why do you do that?

Comment: Post logcat please as you are not telling the whole story. Why not make it clearer to us if you want help.

Comment: I posted logical and updated code

Comment: By the image file size I mean the size of the image on the server's side.

Comment: `totalBytesRead` > `1280*800` hence the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You have to concatenate your reads in a ByteArrayOutputStream (google for bytearrayoutputstream example. Then select the stackoverflow links) instead of overwriting them in your buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`totalBytesRead` > `1280*800` hence the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You have to concatenate your reads in a ByteArrayOutputStream (google for bytearrayoutputstream example. Then select the stackoverflow links) instead of overwriting them in your buffer.
                    – greenapps